# tqdm update after last iteration

Tags: python-3.x, progress-bar, tqdm

I'm using tqdm as a nice progressbar, but after iterating over the progressbar I want to update the description.

The following is a simple example:

```
with tqdm(somelist) as pbar:
  for element in pbar:
    foo(element)

  pbar.set_description('We finished')
```

I get the output:

```
100%|███████████████████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 239674.51it/s]
```

but expected:

```
We finished: 100%|███████████████████████████| 10/10 [00:00<00:00, 239674.51it/s]
```

I've tried `pbar.update()`, `pbar.refresh()` and `refresh=True` as a parameter for `set_description`, neither worked.

Of course, one can always print or use `tqdm.write()`, but would be neater to have besides the progress bar.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this code below? You can check if the current `element` is the last item in `some list` by using the if condition `if element == somelist[-1]`. If the `element` is the last item in `somelist`, then you know it will be finished after this so you can update the `pbar` description

```
with tqdm(somelist) as pbar:
  for element in pbar:
    foo(element)
    if element == somelist[-1]:
        # Update when element is the last item in some list
        pbar.set_description("We finished")
```

Edit: Another way is to use an increasing `i` variable to check if it is at the end of the iteration or now

```
i = 0
with tqdm(somelist) as pbar:
  for element in pbar:
    foo(element)
    i += 1
    if i == len(somelist):
        # Update when element is the last item in some list
        pbar.set_description("We finished")
```

Comment: `somelist` in my case is a pytorch `DataLoader` which isn't subscriptable. I could enumerate over the loader, and check when `len(somelist) == i`, though it is not as nice looking in my opinion and would have a lot of code indented in the if statement.

Comment: @TheisJendal If you can set a variable `I = 0` and increase it by 1 every iteration. We can know if it is the end of the iteration by checking if `len(somelist) == I`